# Disable logging GET /phoenix/live_reload/socket/websocket?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Running phoenix (v1.0.4) there's a message printed to console every few seconds:

`[info] GET /phoenix/live_reload/socket/websocket`

How can I disable this? It makes working in IEx unpleasant.

There's a `config :logger` function in `dev.exs`, but I don't see how to isolate this message. The elixir documentation for `Logger` mentions custom backends. I could take a look at this, but perhaps there's something within phoenix.

I find phoenix's other logged messages useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The live reload logger has been silenced by default for some time now. Are you sure you aren't overriding the log level settings in your UserSocket? Also make sure you are on the latest `phoenix_live_reload` version (1.0.1)

Comment: Yes, quite possible I adjusted something, and then adjusted something else in my attempts to remove the message. I know now where to look to resolve the problem if it occurs again. Thanks Chris.